# Increment counter with button click in recyclerview ( of cardview )

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-cardview

I am working on app that using RecyclerView. I have a Button in each card that when clicked, will count the number of clicks and display it in a TextView in that particular card. The app crashes (Logic Error ) when I run it. What am I doing wrong ?
( I want to setcheck the check box true when counter = counter in Model )

```
public class MorAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MorAdapter.HViewholder> {

private ArrayList<ZekeritemModel> model=new ArrayList<>();





public MorAdapter(ArrayList<ZekeritemModel> models,Context context) {
    this.model = models;
}
@Override
public HViewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.mor_items, parent, false);


    return new HViewholder(v);
}




@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MorAdapter.HViewholder holder, int position) {


    holder.plusbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         int count =0;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            count++;
            holder.plustext.setText(Integer.toString(count));
            if (count==model.get(position).getCounter()){
                holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);}
                           
        }
    });
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return model.size();
}

 class HViewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
  TextView  plustext;
  CircleButton plusbtn;
  CheckBox checkBox;



     HViewholder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        plusbtn=itemView.findViewById(R.id.pluss);
        plustext=itemView.findViewById(R.id.plustext);
        checkBox=itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkk);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can You add logcat?

Comment: that is logic error when i clicked on btn in card (1) then when clicked on btn on card (2) the counter started from 2 not 1

Comment: provide a GIF for your app

Comment: Try to make it count = count+1 instead of count ++

Comment: Not working , But thanks for trying to help me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `currentCount` **property** to your model `ZekeritemModel`
so your model became

```java
public class ZekeritemModel {
.... your code 
.... 
 int currentCount = 0; 
// add your getter and setter ..

}
```

change your **onBind** to

```java
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MorAdapter.HViewholder holder, int position) {
    // get current item
    final ZekeritemModel item = model.get(position);
    int count = item.getCurrentCount();
    // set value of counter inside textview
    holder.plustext.setText(Integer.toString(count));

    holder.plusbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            count++;
            item.setCurrentCount(count);
            holder.plustext.setText(Integer.toString(count));
            if (count==model.get(position).getCounter()){
                holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);}
                           
        }
    });
}
```

**NOTE**  may code some typo or miss some taps, spaces, parenthesis (as i Have no IDE now).

Answer (score 0):

Because you declared "**counter**" as global , you must to add counter to your model

Comment: You do not understand me , I want when click on btn in each card the text ++ and when the counter in text equal to counter in model the checkbox is true ,but now when i clicked on btn in card then clicked on another card the counter in text start from 2 not 1

Comment: your counter is global , every click increase your counter value . u must remove counter as global variable and add it to your model

Comment: Can u show example ,please ? Because I tried many times